# The use of sapply in cross validation

Tags: r, cross-validation

I have a question about `sapply`in R. In my example I'm using it for leave-one-out cross validation

```
 ##' Calculates the LOO CV score for given data and regression prediction function
##'
##' @param reg.data: regression data; data.frame with columns 'x', 'y'
##' @param reg.fcn:  regr.prediction function; arguments:
##'                    reg.x: regression x-values
##'                    reg.y: regression y-values
##'                    x:     x-value(s) of evaluation point(s)
##'                  value: prediction at point(s) x
##' @return LOOCV score
loocv <- function(reg.data, reg.fcn)
{
  ## Help function to calculate leave-one-out regression values
  loo.reg.value <- function(i, reg.data, reg.fcn)
    return(reg.fcn(reg.data$x[-i],reg.data$y[-i], reg.data$x[i]))

  ## Calculate LOO regression values using the help function above
  n <- nrow(reg.data)
  loo.values <- sapply(seq(1,n), loo.reg.value, reg.data, reg.fcn)

  ## Calculate and return MSE
  return(???)
}
```

My questions about `sapply`are the following:

1. Can I use multiple arguments and functions, i.e. `sapply(X1,FUN1,X2,FUN2,..)`, where `X1` and `X2` are my function arguments for the function `FUN1` and `FUN2` respectively.
2. In the above code, I apply `1:n` to the function `loo.reg.value`. However, this function has multiple arguments, in fact 3: integer `i`, regression data `reg.data` and regression function `reg.fcn`. If the function in sapply has more than one argument, and my `X` covers just one of the arguments, does sapply use it as "first argument"? So it would be the same as `sapply(c(1:n,reg.data,reg.fcn),loo.reg.value, reg.data, reg.fcn)`?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega for a comprehensive overview and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490297/apply-different-functions-to-different-elements-of-a-vector-in-r to see how to use multiple functions with multiple arguments.

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft `mapply` has a specific use which is not the same as the use here where you want to apply a function to that takes a function as an argument. Both `mapply` and `sapply` have uses but I don't see how `mapply` applies in this case?

Comment: @GavinSimpson, to answer OP's first question, one could use `mapply(function(f, x) f(x), list(FUN1, FUN2), list(X1, X2))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to the first question, Yes, you can use multiple functions, but second and subsequent functions need to be passed on to first function and then on to next function etc. Hence the functions need to be coded so as to take additional arguments *and* pass them on.

For example

```
foo <- function(x, f1, ...) f1(x, ...)
bar <- function(y, f2, ...) f2(y, ...)
foobar <- function(z, f3, ...) f3(z)

sapply(1:10, foo, f1 = bar, y = 2, f2 = foobar, z = 4, f3 = seq_len)

> sapply(1:10, foo, f1 = bar, y = 2, f2 = foobar, z = 4, f3 = seq_len)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
[2,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2
[3,]    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3     3
[4,]    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4     4
```

This is a silly example but it shows how to pass on extra arguments to `foo()`, *initially*, as part of the `...` argument of `sapply()`. Also it shows how to have `foo()` and subsequent functions *take* extra arguments to be passed on, simply via the use of `...` in the function definition *and* in how the next function is called, e.g. `f2(y, ...)`. Note I also avoid issue with positional matching and name all the additional arguments supplied to `foo()`.

With regard to question 2, I think the way you explain it is over-complicating things. You have, for example, duplicated the `reg.data` and `reg.fcn` bits in what R iterates over with `sapply()`, which isn't correct (it implies you iterate over the 3 things in the vector `c(1:n,reg.data,reg.fcn)`, not over `1:n`).

`sapply(1:n, fun, arg1, arg2)` is equivalent to

```
fun(1, arg1, arg2)
fun(2, arg1, arg2)
....
fun(10, arg1, arg2)
```

whilst `sapply(1:n, fun, arg1 = bar, arg2 = foobar)` is equivalent to

```
fun(1, arg1 = bar, arg2 = foobar)
fun(2, arg1 = bar, arg2 = foobar)
....
fun(10, arg1 = bar, arg2 = foobar)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, my first impression was right: If I have a function `FUN` with arguments `x,y,z`, then `sapply(x,FUN,y,z)` just means, that I "iterated over `x` keeping the other arguments "constant", right?

Answer (score 1):

The function you pass to `sapply` can take as many arguments as you'd like (within reason of course), but it will recycle all but the first arguments for every application.  Have you tried running this code? It looks like it will work.