# Use of mapply to transform a vector element-wise by vector with functions

Tags: r, mapply

have a question concerning the use of `mapply`.

Consider the following 2 cases:
**Case 1** showing a simplified example of what I wish to do. I use mapply to transform my vector k element-wise with the functions stored in vector trans. This works ([related to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490297/apply-different-functions-to-different-elements-of-a-vector-in-r))

In **Case 2** I wish to do something similar, however, I want extra function arguments (here, stored in a).But I might want n function arguments. What I get in this example is a 3x3 matrix with the expected results on the diagonal. I only want the computed output of the diagonal. How?

```
k <- seq(1:3)
# Case 1 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
trans <- c(function(x) x, function(x) 1/x, function(x) x^2)             
# transform vektors elementwise with functions in a "transform" vektor
ktrans   <- mapply(function(f, x) f(x), trans, k)

# 2 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
k <- seq(1:3)
a <- rep(2,3)
transa <- c(function(x,a) x*a, function(x,a) 1/x*a, function(x,a) x^2*a)
ktransa   <- mapply(function(f, x,a) f(x,a), transa, MoreArgs= list(x = k, a= a))

> diag(ktransa)
[1]  2  1 18
```

Comment: **Case 1** does not work unless I delete the `a`, otherwise I get `Error in function (f, x) : unused argument(s) (dots[[3]][[1]])`. What is it you are trying to do exactly? In **case 2** you are feeding a vector into `mapply` that is *supposed* to output a matrix w/ each # in `k` transformed in each way. Ie, 3 numbers each transformed 3 ways = a 3x3 matrix.

Comment: why don't you give your extra arguments in your function call ? i.e mapply(function(f, x) f(x, arg1, arg2, arg3), transa) ??

Comment: I want mapply to return the diag vector of the current mapply output. I.e.the functions in the vector `transa[i]` use `k[i]` and `a[i]` as arguments, ouput is then a vector. With i from 1 to `length(transa)`

@ Karl: isn't that what I have done in case2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Instead of using a list to send the arguments to the function, I did it explicitly:

```
# 3 --- Example with n arguments -----------------------------------
k <- seq(1:3)
a <- rep(2,3)
transa <- c(function(x,a) x*a, function(x,a) 1/x*a, function(x,a) x^2*a)
ktransa   <- mapply(function(f, x, a) f(x,a), transa,x = k , a = a)
```